# Definition of "algebra of sets"

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can I use the following definition?

**Def.**. let be $A$ a set and $B \in \mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(A))$, $(A,B)$ is *algebra of sets* if

- $\emptyset \in B$
- $\forall X \in B( (A-X) \in B)$
- $\forall X,Y \in B((X \cap Y ) \in B)$

It is correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should *seriously* consider writing $X \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$ as $X \subseteq Y$. Writing the former is akin to writing $x = \ln e^y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "is it correct" you mean "is it equivalent to the normal definition" (closed under pairwise intersections, pairwise unions, contains $\emptyset$ and $A$) then the answer is "yes."

The second bullet asserts it is closed under complements and the third under intersections.

Suppose $S,T\in B$. Since $S\cup T=A\setminus((A\setminus S)\cap (A\setminus T))$, and the right hand side consists of complements and intersections of things in $B$, $S\cup T$ is in $B$ as well.

Finally, $A\setminus\emptyset=A$ is in $B$ also, so you have both identities.