# Prove: $(\emptyset,\{\emptyset\})$ is an algebra of sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I must prove the following:

**Prop.**: $(\emptyset,\{\emptyset\})$ is *[algebra of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820726/definition-of-algebra-of-sets)*

**Proof**:

$\emptyset \in \{\emptyset\} $ by hypothesis

$\emptyset -\emptyset=\emptyset$ and by hypothesis $ \emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$

$\emptyset \cup \emptyset= \emptyset$ and by hypothesis $ \emptyset \in \{\emptyset\}$

Therefore $(\emptyset,\{\emptyset\})$ is an *algebra of sets*.. Is it correct?

Comment: This is incomplete. You also, at least, need $\varnothing\cup\{\varnothing\} = \{\varnothing\}\in A$, $\{\varnothing\} - \varnothing = \{\varnothing\}\in A$ (where $A$ is the purported algebra), right?  And also $\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\varnothing\} = \{\varnothing\} \in A$, I suppose.

Comment: @MPW Based on [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820726/definition-of-algebra-of-sets) I've seen the user post, I think s/he's using the notation $(M,A)$ to mean "$A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(M)$ is an algebra of subsets of $M$."

Comment: @rschwieb: Ah, I see. My bad.

Comment: @MPW np! If I hadn't seen that question I would have probably thought the same thing. These comments will probably prevent anyone else from thinking the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\{\emptyset\}$ is an algebra of subsets of the set $\emptyset$. (Actually it's the only nonempty collection of subsets possible. :) )

You've shown the algebra contains the emptyset, is closed under complements and unions, and therefore intersections too.

Comment: This is not correct, is it? The collections $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ are not the same.

Comment: @MPW Hi, please see my comment about the OP's choice of notation above. I don't believe he's claiming that $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ is an algebra.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for pointing out the correct interpretation of the notation in this case. You're absolutely correct. Consider my previous comment(s) retracted.

Comment: @rschwieb.. thanks for answer! :)

Comment: @rschwieb, in generally $(A,\{A,\emptyset\})$ is algebra.. is correct?